# tKinter dialog button not responding

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, dialog

I am new to tKinter. I tried this code and it did not work. When I click any of the buttons(Yes/No), the dialog does not close and the print statement does not 
print. I know in Swing I need events to print this statement. Is it the same in tKinter?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

root = Tk()

answer=tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('Question','what is your name?')
if answer=='Yes':
print('I am King')

root.mainloop()
```

How do I go about correcting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned value would be `'yes'` (all lowercase) , but you are trying to check it against `'Yes'` , hence it does not print. Try checking it against `'yes'` .

Also, the actual application `root` does not close until you click on the `x` button, because you are defining the `Tk()` application and entering its mainloop. If you want it to close (and the program to end with the print statement) , then you do not need the `root=Tk()` or `root.mainloop()` .

Example -

```
import tkinter.messagebox

answer=tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('Question','what is your name?')
if answer=='yes':
    print('I am King')
```

Please note, this would print `'I am King'` into the console.

---

To answer the question in comment -

> Is there a way I can hide the dialog box called tk-- that is the second one in the background?

You will have to create the application using `Tk()` for that, and then you can use `root.withdraw()` on it. Example -

```
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
answer=tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('Question','what is your name?')
if answer=='yes':
    print('I am King')
```

Comment: Is there a way I can hide the dialog box called tk-- that is the second one in the background?

Comment: @BattleDrum I have added a solution for that , you can check now.

Answer (score 1):

You must use indentation under your 'if' statement. I.e:

```
    if answer.lower() == 'yes': # this proofs against mistakes with user capitalisation
        print ('I am the king')
```